# How to animate a DataGrid height

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, wpf-animation

All,

I have a WPF datagrid in which there is a template column defined as follows:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="105">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="35">
                <Button Style="{StaticResource tableButtonStyle}">
                    <ContentControl/>
                </Button>                   
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The button style (which only displays the button when the user moves the mouse over a specific data grid row) is as follows:

```
<!-- Disappearing button for tables -->
<Style x:Key="tableButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}},Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I would like to animate the height of the datagrid so that it is 'X' units high when the buttons are hidden, or 'Y' units high when the buttons are displayed. Can this be achieved in the xaml markup?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a way to do that in XAML(I don't know it because i'm new to xaml).
But what I would do that with code-behind. I would use a fancy animation, something like:

```
private Storyboard sb=new StoryBoard();
private DoubleAnimation da=new DoubleAnimation();
da.From=datagrid.actualHeight;
da.to=x;
da.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, new PropertyPath(yourDatagrid.HeigthProperty));
sb.Children.Add(da);
yourDatagrid.BeginStoryboard(sb);
```

and maybe you can get this inside a ClickEvent.
Hope this help!